# Can't reject or approve suggested edit

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

When I went to look at the review queues I saw [this suggested edit](https://serverfault.com/review/suggested-edits/350175) where the only option is <kbd>Skip</kbd>.

Normally the options are <kbd>Approve</kbd><kbd>Improve Edit</kbd><kbd>Reject and Edit</kbd><kbd>Reject</kbd><kbd>Skip</kbd>. But for this particular suggested edit I am only given the <kbd>Skip</kbd> option.

Comment: Works for me as expected, I won't act on this review though so others can check this as well.  That said, I really dislike this edit...

Comment: @Sven Maybe it looks different for moderators. I might have clicked "Reject and Edit" on that review, if the button had been there. Too many pointless changes in that suggested edit and some of them are strictly for the worse. I did however notice one place where the edit was fixing a mistake in the original.

Comment: I see all the buttons too, but again, diamond powahs... and I'm in the "nopetopus" camp on that edit, as well.  It's invasive _and_ introduces errors.

Comment: I have the same issue with that particular edit review, and would also have rejected it if possible.

Comment: I've now rejected the edit, but I've no clue what the issue was with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments received on this question I believe we can conclude that:

- The particular suggested edit can for some reason only be reviewed by moderators.
- There is consensus that the edit should be rejected.

Before I flag the answer in question for moderator attention I will wait for a few days to see if anybody else have anything to add about the issue.

Comment: Are you sure that you hit a window where the item was selected just before all required reviews were made?  Thus there would be no need for any more reviews.  Agreed that this would be a narrow window but I have run into this occasionally.

Comment: @mdpc The problem was present for at least two weeks every time that particular review came up.

Answer (score 2):

That edit suggestion is for an answer to [a locked question](https://serverfault.com/questions/517501/is-it-possible-for-two-hostnames-share-the-same-ip-address).  Apparently, it was submitted 25 minutes before the question was locked.

Only ♦ mods can edit locked questions or answers to them.  I would assume that the review code determined that, since you're not allowed to edit the answer, you should also not be permitted to review edits to it.  Which does seem rather reasonable, actually.

It could perhaps be argued that locking the question *should* have automatically rejected any pending edit suggestions made to it or to its answers.  Or perhaps the moderator who locked it should at least have been notified about the pending suggestions, and prompted to review them.  That said, this seems like a pretty rare situation, and I can understand that adding extra code to handle it better may not be a high priority for the SE developer.  After all, the situation *was* eventually resolved anyway.